# Program stops running without error

Tags: c++, matrix

I have to calculate the matrix product via straight forward calculation. I wrote the following code:

```
template <typename T>
void multiplicate_straight(T ** A, T ** B, T ** C, int sizeX)
{
    T ** D = AllocateDynamicArray2D<T>(sizeX, sizeX);
    transpose_matrix(B, D,sizeX);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < sizeX; j++)
        {
            for(int g = 0; g < sizeX; g++)
            {
                C[i][j] += A[i][g]*D[j][g];
            }
        }
    }
    FreeDynamicArray2D<T>(D);
}
```

With `size = 12` everything works, but when I set the value to `14`, the program closes itself without throwing any error, return value is 0. The data type of my matrices is `double`.
Is there a problem in my code, or why do I get no error, but no result, too? The matrices `A` and `B` are initialized with random variables, `C` is completely zero.
Edit: Allocation Code:

```
template <typename T> T ** AllocateDynamicArray2D( int nRows, int nCols)
    {
          T **dynamicArray;

          dynamicArray = new T*[nRows];
          for( int i = 0 ; i < nRows ; i++ )
          dynamicArray[i] = new T [nCols];

          return dynamicArray;
    };

int sizeX = 14;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is your `A` or `B` stack/static allocated?

Comment: @C.R.: A and B are allocated via AllocateDynamicArray<double>(sizeX, sizeX), but I don't know if they are stack allocated.

Answer (score 0):

If it's closing itself chances are it's crashing, you should use `try-catch`. Print the content of any caught errors to a log or to console.

Comment: Error: Bad Allocation. So, what does that mean? Does it mean that I am writing outside of my array borders?

Comment: @arc_lupus - show your allocation code. memory allocation failed. could be that `sizeX` has an illegal value. what is it?